# Integrating Angular2 with with browserify

Tags: angular, browserify, systemjs

There are quite a few examples how to use Angular2 systemJS module loader.
How do I integrate Angular2 with browserify? Is it not recommended for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. If you are using typescript, change your module system to "commonjs" in your tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false   
}
```

After transpiling your .ts files to .js files, you can execute browserify on your application's entry point js file. For example:

```
browserify ./js/main.js > ./dist/bundle.js
```

This, of course, can be automated via gulp or grunt as part of your build system.